# Regex to get scriptfunction body

Tags: javascript, android, regex, function, jsoup

I have a document and will need the function body in this document

This is a piece of the document

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  (function(){
    var a = function() {try{return !!window.addEventListener} catch(e) {return !1} },
    b = function(b, c) {a() ? document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", b, c) : document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", b)};
    b(function(){
      var a = document.getElementById('cf-content');a.style.display = 'block';
      setTimeout(function(){
        var t,r,a,f, vsFCUji={"GqfTZuOkv":+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+[]))};
        t = document.createElement('div');
        t.innerHTML="<a href='/'>x</a>";
        t = t.firstChild.href;r = t.match(/https?:\/\//)[0];
        t = t.substr(r.length); t = t.substr(0,t.length-1);
        a = document.getElementById('jschl-answer');
        f = document.getElementById('challenge-form');
        ;vsFCUji.GqfTZuOkv+=+((+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]));vsFCUji.GqfTZuOkv+=!+[]+!![]+!![];vsFCUji.GqfTZuOkv+=+((+!![]+[])+(+[]));vsFCUji.GqfTZuOkv+=+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+[]));vsFCUji.GqfTZuOkv-=+((!+[]+!![]+[])+(+[]));a.value = parseInt(vsFCUji.GqfTZuOkv, 10) + t.length;
        f.submit();
      }, 4000);
    }, false);
  })();
  //]]>
</script>
```

And this is what i need as result from the `setTimeout(function(){` :

```
+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+[]))
```

I will use this command to get the document

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(encoded_url).timeout(10000).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible, MSIE 11, Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0;  rv:11.0) like Gecko").method(Connection.Method.GET).get();
```

Then i run this command to get the function body from the document.

```
Pattern pattern_1 = Pattern.compile("setTimeout\\(function\\(\\)\\{\s*.*?.*:(.*?)};");                 
Matcher m = pattern_1.matcher(document.html());
Log.d("Matcher", "output:" + m.matches());
```

But it gives nothing...

Comment: One problem is that you are using matches that requires a full string match. And another is that there are a lot of lines, and `.` in your case without `Pattern.DOTALL` won't match a newline. And there can be unknown number of `{` and `}`.

Comment: ^ instead of `.*?` use `[\s\S]*?` to catch new lines as well

Answer (score 0):

Solution proposed by `Wiktor Stribiżew`

> One problem is that you are using matches that requires a full string match. And another is that there are a lot of lines, and . in your case without Pattern.DOTALL won't match a newline. And there can be unknown number of { and }.